# Node / Mongoose: res.send() erases previous Mongo update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm updating an object in an array with Mongoose. After it updates I'm firing `res.send()` in the callback.

If I don't fire the `res.send()` the update saves fine. But when I do `res.send()`, the entire object in the array is erased from Mongo.

```
landmarkSchema.findById(tileRes.worldID, function(err, lm) {
  if (!lm){
    console.log(err);
  }
  else if (req.user._id == lm.permissions.ownerID){

    var min = tileRes.zooms[0];
    var max = tileRes.zooms.slice(-1)[0];

    if (lm.style.maps.localMapArray){
      for (var i = 0; i < lm.style.maps.localMapArray.length; i++) { //better way to do this with mongo $set 

          if (lm.style.maps.localMapArray[i].map_marker_viewID == req.body.map_marker_viewID) {

              lm.style.maps.localMapArray[i]['temp_upload_path'] = '';
              lm.style.maps.localMapArray[i]['localMapID'] = tileRes.mapURL;
              lm.style.maps.localMapArray[i]['localMapName'] = tileRes.worldID;

              lm.markModified('style.maps.localMapArray'); 

              lm.save(function(err, landmark) {
                  if (err){
                      console.log('error');
                  }
                  else {
                      console.log('updated map',landmark);
                      //res.status(200).send(landmark);
                  }
              });
          }
      }
    }

  }

});
```

Is it a write issue where Mongo doesn't finish writing before `res.send` is fired?

Comment: Shouldn't the `lm.markModified` and `lm.save` calls be after the `for` loop rather than within it?

Comment: I changed the code to have the `markModified` and `save` outside of the `for` loop but it still does the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

I recommend start using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to iterate in these cases, of course you can do this without it, but you'll have to find a very good reason to avoid using it.

I don't see the rest of your method, but using async it should be similar to this:

```
async.each(lm.style.maps.localMapArray, function(localMap, callback) {    
  // Do whatever you like here
  //....
  // Call method that requires a callback and pass the loop callback
  localMap.iUseACallbackAfterDoingMyStuff(callback);
}, function(err){
    // now here the loop has ended
    if( err ) {
      // Something happened..
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(somethingToTheClient);
    }
});
```

The code snippet is just for you to get the idea.